# Twitter API registration approval issue

Tags: api, twitter

I just want participate in Twitter RecSys Challenge 2020, for that I'd created a twitter developer account and created my app also. But when I tried to log in to http://recsys-twitter.com/ it shows a message like

> Your Twitter API registration is incomplete, you will be able to log
>   in after this is approved.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Wait until it is approved. There is not much you can do. Just be sure that when you applied for a twitter developer account you included a lot of information.

Comment: but twitter api giving me my timeline tweets in my website without approving my developer account. !

Comment: You still have an unapproved developer account.